# How to compile Berkeley DB 5.3.28 for MXE cross-compiler?

Tags: linux, mingw, cross-compiling, berkeley-db

Has anybody a solution for building Berkeley DB for MXE's cross-compile environment?

When I run my build script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 MXE_PATH=/path/to/mxe
 
 db=db-5.3.28

 rm -rf ./$db/build_mxe
 mkdir -p ./$db/build_mxe
 cd ./$db/build_mxe
 
 sed -i "s/WinIoCtl.h/winioctl.h/g" ../src/dbinc/win_db.h

 CC=$MXE_PATH/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-gcc \
 CXX=$MXE_PATH/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++ \

 ../dist/configure \
     --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu \
     --host=x86 \
     --disable-replication \
     --enable-cxx \
     --enable-mingw \
     --prefix=/path/to/dev/mingw_db

  make -j6; make -j6 install
```

The compiler warns of direct.h missing:

```
../src/dbinc/win_db.h:21:20: fatal error: direct.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

direct.h and all dependent files exist in ***mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/include*** directory

So how to force the compiler to use these files ?

Comment: Have you tried passing this directory to the compiler using the -I option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've improved upon my build script and solved my question:

I had to fix the original script which then perfected the build.

The correct syntax goes as follows:

```cpp
#!/bin/bash

## Path to MXE source
 MXE_PATH=/home/demon/dev/mxe
## Path for mingw headers
 MXE_INCLUDE=$MXE_PATH/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/include

## Path to db source
 db=db-6.1.26

## Make a clean working tree and Create working DIR 
## You can also use `make distclean` within build_mxe to start fresh
 
 rm -rf ./$db/build_mxe
 mkdir -p ./$db/build_mxe

## Enter working directory
 cd ./$db/build_mxe

## Correct naming of header file
 sed -i "s/WinIoCtl.h/winioctl.h/g" ../src/dbinc/win_db.h


## Define CC and C++ compiler & user level commands
export CC=$MXE_PATH/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-gcc
export CXX=$MXE_PATH/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++
export AR=$MXE_PATH/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ar
export STRIP=$MXE_PATH/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-strip
export RANLIB=$MXE_PATH/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ranlib

### Find mingw headers in non-standard directory
export CPPFLAGS=-I$MXE_INCLUDE


## Configure the build
 ../dist/configure \
     --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu \
     --host=x86 \
     --disable-replication \
     --enable-cxx \
     --enable-mingw \
     --program-transform-name='s,.exe,,;s,\(.*\),\1.exe,' \
     --prefix=/home/demon/dev/mxe_db \
     --exec-prefix=/home/demon/dev/mxe_db

## Build DB and install it
 make -j(nproc); make -j(nproc) install
```

The corrected issues:

- Set the environment variable to locate mingw headers using the CPPFLAGS variable
- Set correct compiler commands and user commands for CC, CXX, AR, STRIP, and RANLIB environment variables to MXE's compiler with `export <variable>`

That did the trick !

You can follow the complete build here:

https://pastebin.com/aP5rWQSC

Contents of the output (--prefix) directory's finished build:
[image: Build output (--prefix) directory]

Comment: @GregorioLitenstein This should solve the build for you.

Answer (score 0):

The MXE developers have slowly improved the build process for MXE's deps. Berkeley DB is now easy to compile the version you need using `make db` within the MXE source, and if a specific version is needed, you can change it in src/db.mk. and again run `make db` will update the files accordingly.

There is one error during the make process in which libtool doesn't find the db binaries properly due to a current db patch (src/db-2-install-exe.patch) in MXE that's applied during compiling db which will be deprecated. However, in the meantime the fix is to delete the db patch file and add the following flag in src/db.mk with the other configure options after (MXE_CONFIGURE_OPTS):

`--program-transform-name='s,.exe,,;s,\(.*\),\1.exe,' \`

This is much simpler and keeps the MXE source cleaner/manageable than using a custom compile script for BDB.

Comment: I am trying to fix the db build on mxe; I tried this but it's not working; I'm looking at the temp build tree and I can't see any differences from before (and same errors not being able to find the files because they all have the .exe extension)

Comment: Make sure your build tree is clean. Possibly reclone the mxe github. I haven't been at this for a bit. They may have updated their compile process since then. I'm not up to par with the procedure if it has changed. Check https://mxe.cc and https://github.com/mxe. Also refer to https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1080289.0 for some guidance.

Comment: I just attempted a basic mxe setup, compiling mxe  with `make cc` then building db with `make db` and there was no issue. It did compile with db v6.1.26. I then switched it over to version 5.3.28 and also compiled without error.

Comment: I'm using gcc8 and trying to update it to the latest stable (6.1.26, which is what is on master gave me the same issue, though)

Comment: @GregorioLitenstein Could please post the log file that results from the compiling error for gcc and db (separately) on https://pastebin.com/ .  I just got an error myself when using mxe's update script (`make update-package-gcc` (gc also) then `make gcc`) to to check/update gcc which it downloaded version 10.1.0 and 8.0.4 for gc. If we end up having the same errors, then you should file a new issue on mxe's github.

Comment: @GregorioLitenstein The log file should be located in the path (example) >> /path/to/mxe/log/gcc_i686-w64-mingw32.static

Comment: It's not going to be the same because I have no issue building gcc. And my db builds are failing due to unexpected `.exe` extension on generated files; and for some reason it appears the `--program-transform-name` argument is not working.

Comment: @GregorioLitenstein can you DM me on discord demon#9191 ?